# AngularJS custom directive bidirectional binding broken after material upgrade

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material, angular-ngmodel, angular-directive

I wrote a small directive working under Angular 1.6.1 and material 1.1.1.
It is a simple lock/unlock button icon.

I had to update material to 1.1.3 (for the date picker), but since then the directive doesn't work anymore.

I do not understand why a material update would do this....
The plunker below works, but if you change the material version to 1.1.2, it stops working.

http://plnkr.co/edit/ZamxN3WTXaOl5cTv4aWI?p=info

index.html:

```
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.3/angular-material.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-aria.js"></script>

  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.1/angular-material.js"></script>
  <!-- <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.1/angular-material.js"></script> -->

  <script src="script.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller as ctrl">
  <ju-lock ng-model="ctrl.lock"></ju-lock>|{{ctrl.lock}}|
</body>
</html>
```

script.js:

```
  angular
    .module('app', ['ngMaterial'])
    .directive('juLock', function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                bindModel: '=ngModel'
            },
            template: 
                '<md-button class="md-icon-button">'+
                '<md-icon class="material-icons">lock_open</md-icon>'+
                '</md-button>|{{bindModel}}',
            link: function(scope, element, attributes){
                element.on('click', function (ev) {
                    scope.bindModel = !scope.bindModel;
                });
                scope.$watch('bindModel', function(){
                    angular.element(element[0].querySelector('.material-icons')).text(scope.bindModel ? 'lock' : 'lock_open');
                });
            }
        };
    })
    .controller('controller', function(){
        var vm = this;
        vm.lock=true;
    });
```

I have investigated as much as I could before asking the stack community, does anyone have some insight into this?

Comment: Avoid using `ng-model` as an attribute in custom directives. If you do so, don't use isolate scope two-way binding with it. Use the [ngModelController API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) which that attribute instantiates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid using `ng-model` as an attribute in custom directives. If you do so, don't use isolate scope two-way binding with it. Use the [ngModelController API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) which that attribute instantiates.

The main problem is the [jqLite click handler](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#angularjs-s-jqlite) needs to notify the AngularJS framework of changes to scope with [scope().$apply()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply):

```
element.on('click', function (ev) {
    scope.bindModel = !scope.bindModel;
    //USE $apply
    scope.$apply();
});
```

> Angular modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and Angular execution context. Only operations which are applied in Angular execution context will benefit from Angular data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc... You use [$apply()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) to enter Angular execution context from JavaScript.
>
> Keep in mind that in most places (controllers, services) `$apply` has already been called for you by the directive which is handling the event. An explicit call to `$apply` is **needed only when implementing custom event callbacks**, or when working with third-party library callbacks.
>
> [image]
>
> — [AngularJS Developer Guide - Integration with the browser event loop](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#integration-with-the-browser-event-loop)

The [DEMO on PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/v4P9ZuF7OJwmsRPTvfIS?p=preview)

---

Also instead of manipulating DOM to change lock and unlock icons. It can done with the [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) and [ng-hide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide) directives:

```
app.directive('juLock', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            bindModel: '=myModel'
        },
        template: 
            '<md-button class="md-icon-button">'+
            '<md-icon ng-show="bindModel" class="material-icons">lock</md-icon>'+
            '<md-icon ng-hide="bindModel" class="material-icons">lock_open</md-icon>'+
            '</md-button>|{{bindModel}}',
        link: function(scope, element, attributes){
            element.on('click', function (ev) {
                scope.bindModel = !scope.bindModel;
                //USE $apply
                scope.$apply();
            });
            /*
            scope.$watch('bindModel', function(){
                angular.element(element[0].querySelector('.material-icons')).text(scope.bindModel ? 'lock' : 'lock_open');
            });
            */
        }
    };
})
```

Comment: @glorfindel You don't need to use the wayback machine. The image has moved to https://docs.angularjs.org/img/guide/concepts-runtime.png

Comment: Thanks for finding that, my bot isn't able to detect such situations. My browser can't even load https://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/img/guide/concepts-runtime.png and I've never done an angular project myself.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about your exact problem among versions, but check this [fiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/KXQCYAI1nnJkMHQOW4e3?p=preview), this code will work with both versions.

The key point is using `ng-click`, which is from angularJs, rather than depending on `element.on()`, which may vary if you inject `jQuery` or if you not. Plus this way is more declarative

The only change I did was in your directive

```
.directive('juLock', function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                bindModel: '=ngModel'
            },
            template: 
                '<md-button ng-click="bindModel = !bindModel" class="md-icon-button">'+
                  '<md-icon class="material-icons">{{lock_text}}</md-icon>'+
                '</md-button>|{{bindModel}}',
            link: function(scope, element, attributes){
              scope.lock_text = '';
                scope.$watch('bindModel', function(){
                    scope.lock_text = scope.bindModel ? 'lock' : 'lock_open';
                });
            }
        };
    })
```

I also removed dom inspection in your watch, and I did it more in an Angular-Style